# SQL Dev Query with Joins

Tags: sql, oracle, join

As an exercise, I am creating a database for a zoo.  I have an `Animal` table, Zoo Location `ZLoc` and a Moving record `Mrec` table.  The `Zloc` table has an attribute called `region`.  I am trying to `SELECT` all animals that are in the 'North' region. Here is what I try, but it doesn't produce the expected results:

```
SELECT 
    nickname, region 
FROM 
    Animal 
    JOIN MRec USING (Animal_ID) 
    JOIN ZLoc USING (ZLoc_ID)
WHERE region IN ‘North’;
```

`nickname` is the attribute for animals name. `Mrec` acts as the associative between animal and `Zloc`.

To clarify I am using Oracle SQL Developer
And I have made sure the single 'quotes' are correct

Comment: Please post the error

Comment: For starters, your quotes around *North* are wrong. Use normal single-quotes like `'North'`

Comment: Don't use USING. I know it's cool, but it gets so confusing on more complex queries.

Comment: The error is: Error starting at line 2 in command:
SELECT nickname, region FROM Animal JOIN  MRec USING (Animal_ID) JOIN ZLoc  USING (ZLoc_ID)
 WHERE zloc.region IN 'North'
Error at Command Line:3 Column:7
Error report:
SQL Error: ORA-00904: "ZLOC"."REGION": invalid identifier
00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"
Thank you for the advice so far!

Comment: That's an Oracle error. Why have you tagged this [tag:mysql]?

Comment: it is tagged as oracle, sql, and join from what I can see?

Comment: Can you post Zloc Table structure?

Comment: You just answered the question.  A group member had changed it to "reg" without telling me.  Thank you for making me double check! If you post it as the answer I will mark it as the solution.  Thanks again!

Comment: Can you post Zloc Table structure that is the issue.

Answer (score 1):

`IN` requires parentheses as in `IN ('North')`.  Also make sure you are using apostrophes rather than multibyte curly quotes.

Comment: I have just tried this and I am still getting an "invalid identifier" error.  I do think you are correct with the parenthesis though!  Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

As the error message states, the issue is with the table structure itself, SQL Error: ORA-00904: "ZLOC"."REGION": invalid identifier 00904. 00000 - "%s: invalid identifier"

Which implies column: Zloc->region is not available.

```
ORA-00904: invalid identifier
Cause: The column name entered is either missing or invalid.
Action: Enter a valid column name. A valid column name must begin with a letter, be less than or equal to 30 characters, and consist of only alphanumeric characters and the special characters $, _, and #. If it contains other characters, then it must be enclosed in double quotation marks. It may not be a reserved word.
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not positive about your data / table setup but to select all the animals from the region(loc_id) north this should do the trick.  It will select all the animals then joins on the move table (MRec) and then joins onto the location table (ZLoc).  You may have to update the names of the fields but this should pull back your target.

```
SELECT A.NICKNAME, Z.REGION 
FROM ANIMAL A
LEFT JOIN MRec M ON M.NICKNAME = A.NICKNAME 
LEFT JOIN ZLoc Z ON Z.LOC_ID = M.LOC_ID 
WHERE Z.LOC_ID = 'North'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT nickname, region 
FROM Animal inner JOIN MRec
ON animal.animal_ID=MRec.Animal_ID
ON MRec.zloc_ID = zloc.zloc_ID
WHERE zloc.region = 'north'
```

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
SELECT nickname, region 
FROM Animals 
JOIN MRec ON MRec.Animal_ID = Animals.id 
JOIN ZLoc ON MRec.Zloc = ZLoc.id 
WHERE ZLoc.region LIKE 'North'
```

[Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/31b183/2)